# How to make a header not scroll with a list?

Tags: android, listactivity

I have a ListActivity with custom rows, icons, TextViews, etc.  So I am not using the XML ListView resource.  I do have a scrolling list from an Array, and a header on top.  I just want the header not to scroll and be persistent on the screen.  Here is my code:

ListDisplay.java

```
View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null, false);
    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
    setListAdapter(new MyArrayAdapter(this, names));
```

header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#008800"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:text="n/a"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:text="n/a"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="12dp" />
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

rowlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/list_selector" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="28dp"
    android:layout_height="28dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/tv" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="23dp" >
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I don't think I need to display the ArrayAdapter Java code?

Comment: any reason not to use ListView?

Comment: I am not sure how to do that while adding ImageViews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a layout that will include header view and list view. `ListView` items should be set up using [`Adapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html). There are quite a few tutorials on the subject found on the web such as [this one](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

Comment: So my rowlayout.xml and header.xml should be combined to one XML file?

Comment: Not exactly. You should create a layout that will contain header and ListView. and then use rowlayout.xml to populate list items inside Adapter's `getView` method

Comment: Oh, I think i see.  By the way, that tutorial is what I was loosely basing this on.  Except, somewhere along the line, I swore he Abandoned ListView when he introduced the rowlayout.

Comment: Ok, I am still running into issues.  What I do not understand is how to use "ListView" (in XML) while defining my own adapter.  If I create a layout that has (1) header, then (2) ListView, where and how do I reference this?  Here?  " MyArrayAdapter adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this, names); setListAdapter(adapter); "

Comment: you find your list view using `findViewById` and then create adapter and set it using `list.setAdapter()`